# Angular2+ nested module route params empty

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, ng-modules

My app hierarchy is as follows:

1. app(root)

   - Modules (module)

     - Master
     - Detail

       - Nav
       - Create/home (component)
       - Fields (module)

         - Detail (component)
         - Master (component)

modules-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'modules-detail/:module_name', loadChildren: './module-detail/module-detail.module#ModuleDetailModule' },
 { path: '', component: ModulesMasterComponent }
];
```

modules-detail-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
 path: '',
 component: ModulesNavComponent,
 children: [
    { path: '', component: CreateModuleComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: CreateModuleComponent },
    { path: 'fields', loadChildren: './fields/fields.module#FieldsModule' }
 ]
}
];
```

fields-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: FieldsMasterComponent
},
{
  path: ':field_id',
  component: FieldDetailComponent
}
];
```

**Problem**
When i redirect to /modules/testModuleName/fields, I am trying to access my module_name param thats declared in the modules-routing.module (testModuleName).
However, my route params come up empty when i am in the fields module.
I am able to see the param in the create/home component, but not in the child modules. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you accessing the Param
If you are using router.params

Then switch it to router.parent.params and it will get the id. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: After accessing the params from the ActivatedRoute, i was able to find it under route.parent.parent.params as a grandfathered route. Thanks!